# Medical Transfer Apartment Lease

Tags: rent, transfer, lease, tenant

I did a medical transfer from one apartment to a smaller one.  I wasn’t given a date of when everything needed to be removed from the old apartment. Can I be charged rent on both apartments if I was never told this and it’s not in the lease?

Also, my rent started at $697 my portion $419(subsidized)paid this for a couple months. Then the property manager told me my portion was $341, so I paid $341 for several months. Come to find out it should’ve been $601, my portion $385 the entire time.

Now 7mths later I get a 3 day notice on my door for past due. My lease still shows the original $679. Do I owe this?? I paid my rent every month what I was told to from the beginning. Wasn’t my fault they screwed up.

Comment: Talk to a local real estate lawyer.

Comment: Or local tenant assistance agency